# How to access image On browser and on rails Console? I am getting an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

Vendorpart(id: integer, makemodel_id: integer, part_id: integer, price: float, year: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, user_id: integer, image: string, description: text, grade: string, makemodelname: string, partname: string, quantity: integer, featuers: string, weight: integer, productcategories_id: integer, eproccategory_id: integer, days: integer, is_sell: boolean, is_eproc: boolean)

Vendorpart.first

Vendorpart.find(1).image
NoMethodError: private method `select' called for nil:NilClass
    from /home/ryientsoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/carrierwave-1.3.1/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:247:in`active_versions'
    from /home/ryientsoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/carrierwave-1.3.1/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:297:in `retrieve_versions_from_store!'
    from /home/ryientsoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/carrierwave-1.3.1/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:16:in`block in with_callbacks'
    from /home/ryientsoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/carrierwave-1.3.1/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:16:in `each'
    from /home/ryientsoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/carrierwave-1.3.1/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:16:in`with_callbacks'
    from /home/ryientsoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/carrierwave-1.3.1/lib/carrierwave/uploader/store.rb:85:in `retrieve_from_store!'
    from /home/ryientsoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/carrierwave-1.3.1/lib/carrierwave/mounter.rb:35:in`block in uploaders'
    from /home/ryientsoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/carrierwave-1.3.1/lib/carrierwave/mounter.rb:33:in `map'
    from /home/ryientsoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/carrierwave-1.3.1/lib/carrierwave/mounter.rb:33:in`uploaders'
    from /home/ryientsoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/carrierwave-1.3.1/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:142:in `image'
    from /home/ryientsoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/carrierwave-1.3.1/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:366:in`image'
    from (irb):14
    from /home/ryientsoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /home/ryientsoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in`start'
    from /home/ryientsoft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in`require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `'

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask a good question then edit or ask another one.

Comment: Show your model and your carrierwave uploader.

Comment: @arieljuod I can show my model method due to some privacy concern .. can u suggest me where to lookup ?

Comment: Just the `mount` uploader line and the uploader code.